# Missing data, insert rows in Pandas and fill with NAN

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm new to Python and Pandas so there might be a simple solution which I don't see.

I have a number of discontinuous datasets which look like this:

```
ind A    B  C  
0   0.0  1  3  
1   0.5  4  2  
2   1.0  6  1  
3   3.5  2  0  
4   4.0  4  5  
5   4.5  3  3
```

I now look for a solution to get the following:

```
ind A    B  C  
0   0.0  1  3  
1   0.5  4  2  
2   1.0  6  1  
3   1.5  NAN NAN  
4   2.0  NAN NAN  
5   2.5  NAN NAN  
6   3.0  NAN NAN  
7   3.5  2  0  
8   4.0  4  5  
9   4.5  3  3
```

The problem is,that the gap in A varies from dataset to dataset in position and length...

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please make sure you show your code (effort) to other users so that they can understand your problem well and can debug it

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`set_index` and `reset_index` are your friends.

```
df = DataFrame({"A":[0,0.5,1.0,3.5,4.0,4.5], "B":[1,4,6,2,4,3], "C":[3,2,1,0,5,3]})
```

First move column A to the index:

```
In [64]: df.set_index("A")
Out[64]: 
     B  C
 A        
0.0  1  3
0.5  4  2
1.0  6  1
3.5  2  0
4.0  4  5
4.5  3  3
```

Then reindex with a new index, here the missing data is filled in with nans. We use the `Index` object since we can name it; this will be used in the next step.

```
In [66]: new_index = Index(arange(0,5,0.5), name="A")
In [67]: df.set_index("A").reindex(new_index)
Out[67]: 
      B   C
0.0   1   3
0.5   4   2
1.0   6   1
1.5 NaN NaN
2.0 NaN NaN
2.5 NaN NaN
3.0 NaN NaN
3.5   2   0
4.0   4   5
4.5   3   3
```

Finally move the index back to the columns with `reset_index`. Since we named the index, it all works magically:

```
In [69]: df.set_index("A").reindex(new_index).reset_index()
Out[69]: 
       A   B   C
0    0.0   1   3
1    0.5   4   2
2    1.0   6   1
3    1.5 NaN NaN
4    2.0 NaN NaN
5    2.5 NaN NaN
6    3.0 NaN NaN
7    3.5   2   0
8    4.0   4   5
9    4.5   3   3
```

Comment: `new_index = Index(arange(0,5,0.5), name="A")` occurs the error:
NameError: name 'Index' is not defined

Comment: @PV8 if you had imported `import pandas as pd`, then you need to use `pd.Index`.  Or alternatively you can import the `Index` object directly with `from pandas import Index`

Answer (score 5):

Using the answer by EdChum above, I created the following function

```
def fill_missing_range(df, field, range_from, range_to, range_step=1, fill_with=0):
    return df\
      .merge(how='right', on=field,
            right = pd.DataFrame({field:np.arange(range_from, range_to, range_step)}))\
      .sort_values(by=field).reset_index().fillna(fill_with).drop(['index'], axis=1)
```

Example usage:

```
fill_missing_range(df, 'A', 0.0, 4.5, 0.5, np.nan)
```

Answer (score 4):

In this case I am overwriting your A column with a newly generated dataframe and merging this to your original df, I then resort it:

```
    In [177]:

df.merge(how='right', on='A', right = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.arange(df.iloc[0]['A'], df.iloc[-1]['A'] + 0.5, 0.5)})).sort(columns='A').reset_index().drop(['index'], axis=1)
Out[177]:
     A   B   C
0  0.0   1   3
1  0.5   4   2
2  1.0   6   1
3  1.5 NaN NaN
4  2.0 NaN NaN
5  2.5 NaN NaN
6  3.0 NaN NaN
7  3.5   2   0
8  4.0   4   5
9  4.5   3   3
```

So in the general case you can adjust the `arange` function which takes a start and end value, note I added 0.5 to the end as ranges are open closed, and pass a step value.

A more general method could be like this:

```
In [197]:

df = df.set_index(keys='A', drop=False).reindex(np.arange(df.iloc[0]['A'], df.iloc[-1]['A'] + 0.5, 0.5))
df.reset_index(inplace=True) 
df['A'] = df['index']
df.drop(['A'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.reset_index().drop(['level_0'], axis=1)
Out[197]:
   index   B   C
0    0.0   1   3
1    0.5   4   2
2    1.0   6   1
3    1.5 NaN NaN
4    2.0 NaN NaN
5    2.5 NaN NaN
6    3.0 NaN NaN
7    3.5   2   0
8    4.0   4   5
9    4.5   3   3
```

Here we set the index to column `A` but don't drop it and then reindex the df using the `arange` function.

Answer (score 0):

An solution with pandas `merge` and we assume that your dataframe is sorted by the column `A`:

```
#create full dataframe with the range for A 0.5 till 4.5 in this case
df_help= pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : range(df['A'].min(), df['A'].max()+0.5 ,0.5),
                        'Helper': range(df['A'].min(), df['A'].max()+0.5 ,0.5)
                        })

#Do a right join to get all the ranges and delete the Helper column
df = pd.merge(df, df_help, how='right', on=['A']).drop(['Helper'], axis=1)

#Delete the help dataframe
del df_help
```

Answer (score -3):

This question was asked a long time ago, but I have a simple solution that's worth mentioning. You can simply use NumPy's NaN. For instance:

```
import numpy as np
df[i,j] = np.NaN
```

will do the trick.