# Inserting rows into dataframe by reindexing

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a [dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4il6t751qjmmzkz/Test%20data.tsv?dl=0)
with temperature as one column. Due to how the heater works, there are a number of gaps in the data. In order to make different data sets directly comparable, I want to fill in these missing temperatures and add corresponding NaNs in another column.

I've tried to use the answer given here, which seems to be exactly what I want: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909984/missing-data-insert-rows-in-pandas-and-fill-with-nan.).
But that doesn't work - I get a data frame with the new temperature values I want, but the corresponding data has gone:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np           
A1 = pd.read_table('Test data.tsv', encoding='ISO-8859-1', header = 2) 
A1.columns = ['time',2,3,4,5,6,7,'freq',9,10,11,12,13,'temp',15,16,17,18,19] 
A1truncated = A1[A1.temp >= 25]; A1truncated=A1truncated[A1truncated.temp <= 350.1]
A1averaged = A1truncated.groupby(['temp'], as_index=False)['freq'].mean() 
A1averaged = np.around(A1averaged, decimals=1)

A1averaged.set_index('temp') 
new_index = pd.Index(np.arange(25, 350, 0.1), name='temp')
A1indexed = A1averaged.set_index('temp').reindex(new_index).reset_index()
```

---

Turns my 19 columns into 1 with temperature as the index (A1averaged), then into 2 columns with new temperature list and a column of empty data (A1indexed).
Any ideas why this doesn't work? Or another method to do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index with float can `reindex` with problem, inconsistency is probably because of floating point accuracies. So I use little hack - `Int64Index` instead of `Float64Index`.

I try to set subset easier way:

```
A1truncated = A1[(A1.temp >= 25) & ( A1.temp <= 350.1)]
```

then omit first set index, because is set twice:

```
A1averaged.set_index('temp')
```

set `new_index` to `Int64Index`:

```
new_index = pd.Index(np.arange(250, 3500), name='temp')
```

and use `Int64Index` by multiply column `temp` by `10` and last this column is divided by `10`.

```
A1averaged['temp'] = A1averaged['temp'] * 10
A1indexed['temp'] = A1indexed['temp'] / 10
```

All together:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np           
A1 = pd.read_table('Test data.tsv', encoding='ISO-8859-1', header = 2) 

A1.columns = ['time',2,3,4,5,6,7,'freq',9,10,11,12,13,'temp',15,16,17,18,19] 

A1truncated = A1[(A1.temp >= 25) & ( A1.temp <= 350.1)]

A1averaged = A1truncated.groupby(['temp'], as_index=False)['freq'].mean() 
A1averaged = np.around(A1averaged, decimals=1)
new_index = pd.Index(np.arange(250, 3500), name='temp')

A1averaged['temp'] = A1averaged['temp'] * 10
A1indexed = A1averaged.set_index('temp').reindex(new_index).reset_index()
A1indexed['temp'] = A1indexed['temp'] / 10
print A1indexed.tail()
#       temp       freq
#3245  349.5  5830065.6
#3246  349.6  5830043.5
#3247  349.7  5830046.3
#3248  349.8  5830025.3
#3249  349.9  5830015.6
```