# how to add NaN groupwise for missing values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame analogous to this one:

```
import pandas

dd = pandas.DataFrame({'name' : ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar',
                                 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar'],
                       'year' : ['1900', '1903', '1904', '1900',
                                 '1901', '1902', '1903', '1904'],
                       'value' : np.arange(8)
                       })
```

Further along the pipeline I will need to compare `foo` and `bar` in terms of magnitudes derived from `value`. This is why I would like to add rows for the missing years in `foo` and fill them with `NaN`.

So the final `dd` should have additional rows and look like this:

```
   value name  year
0    0.0  foo  1900
1    NaN  foo  1901
2    NaN  foo  1902
3    0.1  foo  1903
4    0.2  foo  1904
5    0.3  bar  1900
6    0.4  bar  1901
7    0.5  bar  1902
8    0.6  bar  1903
9    0.7  bar  1904
```

I tried using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909984/missing-data-insert-rows-in-pandas-and-fill-with-nan) but it doesn't work in this case because I have duplicate values in the `year` column.

I realize I have to add rows grouping by `'name'` but I couldn't see how.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
dd.set_index(['name','year']).value.unstack().stack(dropna=False).reset_index()
Out[983]: 
  name  year    0
0  bar  1900  3.0
1  bar  1901  4.0
2  bar  1902  5.0
3  bar  1903  6.0
4  bar  1904  7.0
5  foo  1900  0.0
6  foo  1901  NaN
7  foo  1902  NaN
8  foo  1903  1.0
9  foo  1904  2.0
```

Comment: @Federico when you doing the unstack , it will change reshape your df , with index=name . column = year, in this situation , when there is missing year in your original df , it will fillna with taht , after we using stack (dropna=True), if will convert back to the format as your original df

Comment: For optimization I tried using `.reset_index(inplace=True)` but I get `TypeError: Cannot reset_index inplace on a Series to create a DataFrame`. Any ideas?

Comment: @Federico using to_frame() before reset_index